# How to run eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I've installed Java JDK and eclipse IDE successfully in my system but every time I run Eclipse IDE and use the `JFrame`, `JPanel` and other J2SE imports this error message is present:

```
Access restriction: The type JFrame is not accessible 
  due to restriction on required library 
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Administrator rights should solve that...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have faced (something same..) problem when i passed from java 7 to java 8 but the Eclipse shown me that no Java exist in my pc(think that the same bug).

I will give you a webpage that i reinstall the java(it's not the best solution but give a try) **unistall completely java and eclipse** and install it from here this [link here](https://ninite.com/)

1.In developer tools select JDK(32 or 64)

2.In Runtime select Java

That worked for me when i had this problem

Let me know if that works for you...